# Fail to start a newly generated project

Tags: quarkus

I created a brand new project based on instruction on the website :

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.2.Final:create \                                                                           
-DprojectGroupId=com.test.picco \
-DprojectArtifactId=picco \
-DclassName="com.test.picco.Application" \
-Dpath="./picco-backend"
```

then

```
    ~/s/picco λ ./mvnw compile                                                                                                                      ✘ 1
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] The POM for com.google.guava:guava:jar:30.1-jre is missing, no dependency information available
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------< com.redinterface.timeline:picco >-------------------
    [INFO] Building picco 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.2.Final:generate-code (default) @ picco ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  1.494 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-09T22:22:36-05:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.2.Final:generate-code (default) on project picco: Execution default of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.2.Final:generate-code failed: A required class was missing while executing io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.2.Final:generate-code: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    extension>io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.2.Final
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-maven-plugin/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-maven-plugin-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-core/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-core-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/commons-logging-jboss-logging/1.0.0.Final/commons-logging-jboss-logging-1.0.0.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logmanager/jboss-logmanager-embedded/1.0.6/jboss-logmanager-embedded-1.0.6.jar
    [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-embedder/3.6.3/maven-embedder-3.6.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-connector-basic/1.4.1/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.4.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-transport-wagon/1.4.1/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.4.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http/3.3.4/wagon-http-3.3.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/3.3.4/wagon-http-shared-3.3.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/jsoup-1.11.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar
    [ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.14/commons-codec-1.14.jar
    [ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.14/httpcore-4.4.14.jar
    [ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/3.3.4/wagon-file-3.3.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-io/1.5.0/smallrye-common-io-1.5.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/common/wildfly-common/1.5.4.Final-format-001/wildfly-common-1.5.4.Final-format-001.jar
    [ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/gizmo/gizmo/1.0.6.Final/gizmo-1.0.6.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.0/asm-util-9.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.0/asm-tree-9.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.0/asm-analysis-9.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.2.2.Final/jandex-2.2.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.0/asm-9.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-development-mode-spi/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-development-mode-spi-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-class-change-agent/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-class-change-agent-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-utilities/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-devtools-utilities-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.4/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-core-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config/1.10.2/smallrye-config-1.10.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-annotation/1.5.0/smallrye-common-annotation-1.5.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config-common/1.10.2/smallrye-config-common-1.10.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/microprofile-config-api/1.4/microprofile-config-api-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-expression/1.5.0/smallrye-common-expression-1.5.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-function/1.5.0/smallrye-common-function-1.5.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-constraint/1.5.0/smallrye-common-constraint-1.5.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-classloader/1.5.0/smallrye-common-classloader-1.5.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/2.2.0.Final/jboss-logging-annotations-2.2.0.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/threads/jboss-threads/3.2.0.Final/jboss-threads-3.2.0.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[43] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-runner/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-runner-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[44] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-builder/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-builder-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[45] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/sdk/graal-sdk/20.3.1/graal-sdk-20.3.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[46] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-platform-descriptor-json/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-platform-descriptor-json-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[47] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-common/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-devtools-common-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[48] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-codestarts/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-devtools-codestarts-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[49] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-message-writer/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-devtools-message-writer-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[50] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/qute/qute-generator/1.11.2.Final/qute-generator-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[51] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/qute/qute-core/1.11.2.Final/qute-core-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[52] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/reactive/mutiny/0.12.5/mutiny-0.12.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[53] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[54] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-platform-descriptor-api/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-platform-descriptor-api-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[55] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.jar
    [ERROR] urls[56] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/maven-model-helper/18/maven-model-helper-18.jar
    [ERROR] urls[57] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1.3/jdom-1.1.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[58] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.11.3/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[59] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27.jar
    [ERROR] urls[60] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-websockets-jsr/3.0.18.Final/quarkus-http-websockets-jsr-3.0.18.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[61] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-core/3.0.18.Final/quarkus-http-core-3.0.18.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[62] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-http-core/3.0.18.Final/quarkus-http-http-core-3.0.18.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[63] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.49.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[64] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.49.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[65] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.49.Final/netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[66] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.49.Final/netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[67] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.49.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[68] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.49.Final/netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[69] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.49.Final/netty-handler-4.1.49.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[70] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/http/quarkus-http-servlet/3.0.18.Final/quarkus-http-servlet-3.0.18.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[71] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/4.0.3/jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[72] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/websocket/jakarta.websocket-api/1.1.2/jakarta.websocket-api-1.1.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[73] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.11.2.Final-1.11.2.Final.json
    [ERROR] urls[74] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-platform-descriptor-resolver-json/1.11.2.Final/quarkus-platform-descriptor-resolver-json-1.11.2.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[75] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar
    [ERROR] urls[76] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[77] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/1.0/jakarta.inject-api-1.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[78] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/enterprise/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api/2.0.2/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api-2.0.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[79] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/el/jakarta.el-api/3.0.3/jakarta.el-api-3.0.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[80] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/interceptor/jakarta.interceptor-api/1.2.5/jakarta.interceptor-api-1.2.5.jar
    [ERROR] urls[81] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.25/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
    [ERROR] urls[82] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[83] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
    [ERROR] urls[84] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.6.3/maven-builder-support-3.6.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[85] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-util/1.4.1/maven-resolver-util-1.4.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[86] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[87] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.8.0/commons-io-2.8.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[88] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
    [ERROR] urls[89] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[90] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.jar
    [ERROR] urls[91] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/2.1.0/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[92] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.11/commons-lang3-3.11.jar
    [ERROR] urls[93] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.10.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.10.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[94] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[95] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[96] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
    [ERROR] urls[97] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar
    [ERROR] urls[98] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.30/freemarker-2.3.30.jar
    [ERROR] urls[99] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.json/1.1.6/jakarta.json-1.1.6.jar
    [ERROR] urls[100] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.3/jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[101] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.3/jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[102] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.3/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar
    [ERROR] urls[103] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.3.1/mojo-executor-2.3.1.jar
    [ERROR] urls[104] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/slf4j/slf4j-jboss-logmanager/1.1.0.Final/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar
    [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] : com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutureFailureAccess
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like an invalid/partial jar stuck in your local Maven cache.

Could you try with a clean `~/.m2/repository/` (just move yours away before trying)?